# Store maximum number value into database table

Tags: php, mysql

i have this code that makes a sum of 2 tables

```
<div align="right">   Total Vanzari ziua curenta: <i><strong>
<?php
$query = "SELECT (SELECT SUM(totaldeplata) FROM vanzari WHERE 
datainregistrarii  >= CURRENT_DATE()) + (SELECT SUM(totaldeplata) FROM 
players WHERE datainregistrarii  >= CURRENT_DATE()) as result";
$query_run = mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run); 
$sum = $row['result'];
echo "sum of two different column from two tables : "+ $sum;
?></strong>  </i> Lei
</div>
```

it display a sum of 2 row from 2 different tables

is there a way to store this maximul value into database (its actually the daily sale so the maximum value need to be stored into a table row)

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Make **sure** your user parameters are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) or you will end up with severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: You obviously were able to store each of the individual values, so what's your problem storing the sum? Where's your attempt to do so?  Try to avoid asking "is there a way to..." questions.  The answer is almost always "yes".

Comment: im trying to create a chart :) of daily sale and i think i need to store the sum?

Comment: Hi, There is a wrong here, You cannot use + between string and number it will print only the number because he think the string equal to zero, So you want to use `,` or `.` instead. `echo "sum of two different column from two tables : " . $sum;`

Comment: Please try to explain (a lot) better what you really want to achieve. We also need the tables' structure and the relations between them. Right now you are just asking: "_I have this total value and I want to store it in the database. How?_" I don't think you wanted to ask just that :-) P.S: And please translate the table/column names in english.

Comment: well actualy im trying to create a chart that will pick the daily sum of what has been sold. i toguth first i need to store the total sum :)

Comment: In order to store the sums per day you need to create a `total_vanzari_per_day` table. The question is, what if you want to create a chart/report with total vanzari per last 10 days, per month, semester, year, etc? You know what I mean?

Comment: The point is, you have all the base data that you need: totaldeplata for each sale. In order to bring its sums, maximums, etc, in a chart/report you don't need to save those nowhere. This gives you the flexibility to change the fetch criterias in any moment. Just create the proper sql statements for fetching the sums, maximums, etc, and build your charts or reports based on the fetched data. If you still want to save the sums, then they have to be changed each time a `totaldeplata` value changes. Either by implementing an additional update sql statement or by creating...

Comment: ... triggers (`on after insert` and `on after update`) on both tables (`vanzari` and `players`).